# Emacs predictive mode and LaTeX

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, latex, auctex

I am trying to use Emacs [predictive mode](http://www.dr-qubit.org/emacs.php#predictive) with Auctex to edit LaTeX documents. I want to disable the hotkey feature for selecting alternative suggestions and use either a pop-up menu or in-place cycling of the choices using TAB.

The documentation suggests that the hotkey feature can be turned off by setting 
completion-use-hotkeys to nil, but there is no such  variable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got predictive-mode activated when you look for the variable?

Answer (score 0):

try using the variable completion-ui-use-hotkeys